# Manga where the MC is a magician who gets reincarnated and adopted by goblins

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga is about a magician who gets reincarnated as a noble but gets abandoned by his father. he was later adopted by a goblin and he turns his village into a monster kingdom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

*[Suterareta Tensei Kenja - Mamono no Mori de Saikyou no Daima Teikoku o Tsukuriageru](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/suterareta-tensei-kenja-mamono-no-mori-de-saikyou-no-daima-teikoku-wo-tsukuriageru-light-novel)* aka *The Abandoned Reincarnated Wise Man: Creating the Strongest Empire in the Forest of Demons*

[image: Front cover of Suterareta Tensei Kenja - Mamono no Mori de Saikyou no Daima Teikoku o Tsukuriageru]

> A man once called a great wise man was reincarnated just before his death, retained his memories because of the magic he applied to himself. But at times he was born, magic was unnecessary; therefore, the baby was abandoned in the demon forest. He was worried that he would eventually die, but he was lucky enough to be picked up by a gentle goblin and raised at a demon village. The matured wise man tries to develop the village to pay back to the demons, but things start to happen. One who was praised as a wise man leads demons to create a great empire!?

Found with a search for `manga magician "adopted * goblin"`